# Google API cannot display Analytics API options

Tags: google-analytics, google-api, google-analytics-api

In the Google Developer Console I'm trying to access the Analytics API but it hangs at this page:[image: Google Developer Console API screenshot]

Opening the console shows the following error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/analytics/v3/rest. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://console.developers.google.com' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Works for me, are you still having this issue?

Comment: I am, yes. I tried creating new projects, new credentials, etc. but still getting the Access-Control error.

Comment: same issue here, same error in dev console. chrome version 37.0.2062.124